# magento dataflow php customer import

Tags: php, magento, import, dataflow

I have succesfully been using a script that can be called from php / url that runs a dataflow profile to export,however, when i change the profile id to run an import it doesnt work.
Ive have searched forum after forum and it seems all anyone wants to do is export. Please can on of you kind folks look at this script or suggest another script that will succesfully run a import dataflow profile.

Thank you in advance, Jenny

export script :-

```
<?php

$profileId = 5; #The ID of the profile from the administration view

require_once 'app/Mage.php';

umask(0);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');

$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');

$userModel->setUserId(0);

Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);

$profile->load($profileId);

if (!$profile->getId()) {

 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('[ERROR] Invalid ID');

}

Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);

$profile->run();

$recordCount = 0;

?>
```

Comment: There is a magento stackoverflow, suggest posting it there. http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Jenny, Did you got an answer to this. I am also struggling with this.